# jq nested reduce/grouping of JSON data

Tags: bash, json, jq

I'm working on a large JSON dataset (1GB+) and need to merge similar array objects, then merge their nested similar objects.
Starting with, I have rows such as:

```
[{"item": "item1", "attributes":[{"type": "itemtype", "colour": ["blue"]}]},
{"item": "item1", "attributes":[{"type": "itemtype", "colour": ["grey"]}]},
{"item": "item2", "attributes":[{"type": "itemtype", "colour": ["blue"]}]},
{"item": "item2", "attributes":[{"type": "itemtype2", "colour": ["orange"]}]},
{"item": "item2", "attributes":[{"type": "itemtype2", "colour": ["blue"]}]},
{"item": "item3", "attributes":[{"type": "itemtype", "colour": ["blue"]}]}]
```

I have used jq to group by and pretty print these with the code:

```
 jq 'group_by(.item) | map({"item": .[0].item, "attributes": map(.attributes[])})
```

To group by the item, and sort of combine the attributes:

```
[
  {
    "item": "item1",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "type": "itemtype",
        "colour": [
          "blue"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "itemtype",
        "colour": [
          "grey"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": "item2",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "type": "itemtype",
        "colour": [
          "blue"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "itemtype2",
        "colour": [
          "orange"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "itemtype2",
        "colour": [
          "blue"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": "item3",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "type": "itemtype",
        "colour": [
          "blue"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My challenge is grouping these nested attributes together, grouping by type and adding the colours to one array based on the type. So for example I'd have something like:

```
[
  {
    "item": "item1",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "type": "itemtype",
        "colour": [
          "blue",
          "grey"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": "item2",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "type": "itemtype",
        "colour": [
          "blue"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "itemtype2",
        "colour": [
          "orange",
          "blue"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": "item3",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "type": "itemtype",
        "colour": [
          "blue"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried online editors that use Lodash or JMESPath to try and understand it better, as well as tried to add another `map()` within `map(.attributes[])` but am not getting anywhere. I think I need to add reduce() somewhere, but I can't get my head around it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for this question. It was enjoyable to work with.

---

Here's a variation without any `reduce`:

```
group_by(.item) |
map({
    item: first.item,
    attributes: (
        group_by(.attributes[].type) |
        map({
            type: first.attributes[].type,
            colour: ( map(.attributes[].colour[]) )
        })
    )
})
```

I start by grouping the original elements by their `item` key.  This gives us an array that is grouped by `item`. Each element in that array consists of a sub-array containing all the original objects with the same `item`.

The first `map()` brings these groups together by creating one object for each group.  The object has `item` and `attributes` keys, and the value for the `item` key is taken arbitrarily from the first element of the group (they are all the same).

A further `group_by()` and `map()` creates the value for the `attributes` key.  This time grouping over the `type` key down in the `attributes` array of the original objects and, for each created group, collecting the `type` and `colour` values from the original objects.

---

You can also do it with `reduce`, like so:

```
group_by(.item) |
map(reduce .[] as $a ({}; .item = $a.item | .attributes += $a.attributes)) |
map(.attributes |= (
    group_by(.type) |
    map(reduce .[] as $a ({}; .type = $a.type | .colour += $a.colour))
))
```

This is more or less `group_by()`+`map(reduce)` to create the outer structure of the result, i.e., the grouping of the data into parts based on `item` and organising that outer structure.  The values for the `attributes` array are just passed along.

This pattern (`group_by()`+`map(reduce)`) is then repeated for each group's `attributes` array for grouping and organising it based on the `type` values.

---

Performance-wise, the two solutions above are on par with each other for small inputs, with the second variant (using `reduce`) being a bit faster for inputs less than 150 times the size in the question (about 64 KB). For these size inputs, a run takes about 70 ms on my system, i.e. the run time is negligible.

When the input grows further, the `reduced`-based solution seems to require exponentially more time.  For an input of size 4 MB, the first code uses around 800 ms, while the second clocks in at 25 seconds for a single run.

If `jq` becomes difficult to run for larger inputs (a linear extrapolation suggest it should take me about 54 hours to run a 1 GB data set), you may want to look into processing the data in some way (potentially in a database or at least work with the data in some other format which is not JSON).

For example, the given data could be transformed into CSV:

```
item,type,colour
item1,itemtype,blue
item1,itemtype,grey
item2,itemtype,blue
item2,itemtype2,orange
item2,itemtype2,blue
item3,itemtype,blue
```

... or into an equivalent database table, and then worked on from there.

For example, with Miller,

```
$ mlr --csv nest --ivar ';' -f colour file.csv
item,type,colour
item1,itemtype,blue;grey
item2,itemtype,blue
item2,itemtype2,orange;blue
item3,itemtype,blue
```